# How to set a column to a value, if a substring appears anywhere on a line in a CSV?

Tags: regex, linux, csv, awk, sed

I have a csv file that has entries like this:

```
id,name,status,taglist
1,nobody,closed,"something,something else,rambling,blah,No Show,blah"
2,quitter,closed,"something,stuff,nonsense,blah"
3,somebody,accepted,"something,more stuff,sure thing,blah"
```

When 'no show' appears in the taglist column, I need to change 'closed' to 'no show' in the status column. I'm able to find the no show lines like this:

```
awk '/No Show/' < myfile.csv > noshowsonly.csv
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to only update the status column so that the result would look like this:

```
id,name,status,taglist
1,nobody,No Show,"something,something else,rambling,blah,No Show,blah"
2,quitter,closed,"something,stuff,nonsense,blah"
3,somebody,accepted,"something,more stuff,sure thing,blah"
```

I've tried lines like:

```
awk '{if($4 ~ /No Show/) { $3="No Show"}}1' < myfile.csv > updated.csv
```

But that isn't working and I'm stumped.

Comment: Why are you looking for No Show in field 11? None of your lines has that many fields.

Comment: You need to use the `-F,` option to set the field separator to comma, otherwise it uses whitespace by default. Also, `awk` doesn't recognize quotes as surrounding a field, it will treat the commas inside the quotes as field separators.

Comment: ... unless you use GNU awk with `FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]*")'` instead of `-F','`.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry about that, I meant to make that a $4 in this example. The real file I'm working with has 11 columns, and I was a little quick in my editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for FPAT and assuming you really only want to test the 4th field rather than the whole line:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]*")' -v OFS=',' '$4 ~ /No Show/{$3="No Show"} 1' file
id,name,status,taglist
1,nobody,No Show,"something,something else,rambling,blah,No Show,blah"
2,quitter,closed,"something,stuff,nonsense,blah"
3,somebody,accepted,"something,more stuff,sure thing,blah"
```

or if you want to get even more specific of which subfield in the 4th field to test:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]*")' -v OFS=',' '{split($4,f,OFS)} f[5]=="No Show"{$3="No Show"} 1' file
id,name,status,taglist
1,nobody,No Show,"something,something else,rambling,blah,No Show,blah"
2,quitter,closed,"something,stuff,nonsense,blah"
3,somebody,accepted,"something,more stuff,sure thing,blah"
```

otherwise it's just:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} /No Show/{$3="No Show"} 1' file
id,name,status,taglist
1,nobody,No Show,"something,something else,rambling,blah,No Show,blah"
2,quitter,closed,"something,stuff,nonsense,blah"
3,somebody,accepted,"something,more stuff,sure thing,blah"
```

Comment: The third example works best for me in this case, because it will catch the tag I'm looking for even when someone erroneously enters it into the wrong field on occasion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A sed solution:

```
sed '/No Show/s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)closed,/\1No Show,/'
```

To write a new file as in your example:

```
sed '/No Show/s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)closed,/\1No Show,/' myfile.csv > updated.csv
```